# Difference between joint eigenstate and a single eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In angular momentum, we define $m,l$ as a joint eigenstate for $J_{z}$ and $J^{2}.$ Why is there any need to introduce $2$ variables to define an eigenstate? What difference it makes if we use just a single eigenstate for $J_{z}$ and $J^{2}$. Will the expectation value of $J_{x}$ and $J_{y}$ change if we calculate them for a single eigenstate?

Comment: Because $J^2$ and $J_z$ commute, you can diagonalize them simultaneously. Therefore there are two eigenvalues in the problem that can be simultaneously carried by a state. One eigenvalue $\ell$ for $J^2$ and another $m$ for $J_z$.  What do you mean mathematically with "*a single eigenstate for $J_z$ and $J^{2}$*"?

Comment: The point is that e.g. $|l\rangle$ does not describe an eigenstate of $J_z$ and $J^2$ since this could represent $2l+1$ different states. If you meant this with your question

Answer (score 1):

Since $J_z$ commutes with $J^2$, they share a common eigenbasis (an eigenstate in this case). But that does not neccesarily mean they have the same eigenvalues (for instance, they could differ in magnitude), so you use $m$ to refer to $J_z$ eigenvalues and $l$ to $J^2$ ones.
That's why you use $m,l$ (or $m,\lambda$ depending on bibliography), but  you're denoting one eigenvector anyways. It's just notation.